# How to validate invalid partition name while reading from a kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am writing some code to read specific message from Kafka Topic based on partition number and offset, code is as follows

```
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(this.topicName, partition);
this.consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition));
this.consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset);
ConsumerRecords<Object, Object> records = this.consumer.poll(50000L);
```

Now here if wrong value is passed in `partition` variable I want the code to throw the error , but right now it works and just not fetch any record. So I am unable to distinguish when there is no record with given input or the input given are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use one of the methods that retrieves the cluster metadata to find existing partitions.

For example, you can call [`partitionsFor()`](https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#partitionsFor(java.lang.String)), or [`listTopics()`](https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#listTopics()) to get the list of existing partitions for a topic. Then you can detect if the provided `partition` exists or not.